# How can i uninstall beautifulsoup from source?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I installed extracting BeautifulSoup-3.2.0.tar.gz

```
python setup.py install
```

What's the command to uninstall it from it? I noticed there is a linux distro specific package available named python-beautifulsoup. I want to install the system specific beautifulsoup.

What i tried:

```
python setup.py uninstall
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
pip uninstall BeautifulSoup
```

(There should be a package called `python-pip` for the pip command).

If that doesn't work, you'll have to work out where BeautifulSoup is installed, and delete it. You can see where a module is at an interactive prompt:

```
>>> import BeautifulSoup
>>> BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: I removed manually from `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/`

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall python-beautifulsoup just follow these instructions.

**Uninstall just python-beautifulsoup**

`sudo apt-get remove python-beautifulsoup`  This will remove just the python-beautifulsoup package itself.

**Uninstall python-beautifulsoup and its dependencies**

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python-beautifulsoup
```

This will remove the python-beautifulsoup package and any other dependant packages which are no longer needed.

**Purging your config/data too**

If you also want to delete your local/config files for python-beautifulsoup then this will work.

*Caution!* Purged config/data can not be restored by reinstalling the package.

```
sudo apt-get purge python-beautifulsoup
```

Or similarly, like this python-beautifulsoup

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python-beautifulsoup
```